# Concatenation of two strings does not work

Tags: fortran, string-concatenation

I have the following code, but it doesn't work:

```
 CHARACTER*260 xx, yy, zz     
  xx = 'A'   
  yy = 'B'
  zz = xx // yy
```

When I debug my code in Visual Studio the

- variable `xx` contains 'A'
- variable `yy` contains 'B'
- variable `zz` contains 'A'

Why doesn't `zz` contain 'AB'?

Answer (score 23):

You defined `xx` to be 260 characters long. Assigning a shorter character literal will result in a padding with blanks. Thus, `xx` contains `A` and 259 blanks. `yy` contains `B` and 259 blanks. So the concatenated string would be `'A'` + 259 blanks + `'B'` + 259 blanks, in total 520 characters.

Since `zz` is only 260 characters long, the rest is cropped.

What you are trying to do is achieved by

```
zz = trim(xx) // trim(yy)
```

[`trim()`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/TRIM.html) removes trailing whitespace from strings.

Comment: The trim of yy is unnecessary but does not cause a problem either.