# How to combine two strings in Fortran

Tags: printing, fortran

Here's an example in python3 of what I want to do in Fortran:

```
str1 = "Hello"
str2 = " World!"
print(str1 + str2)

# And then the result would be "Hello World!"
```

When I do:

```
print "(A)", str1, str2
```

It puts it on a separate line.  If anyone knows how to help please answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The literal answer to string concatenation, using the `//` operator, is given in another answer.  Note, particularly, that you likely want to `TRIM` the first argument.

But there is another interesting concept your question raises, and that is *format reversion*.

With the format `(A)` we have one format item.  In the output list `str1, str2` we have two output items.  In a general output statement we apply each format item (with repeat counts) to a corresponding output item.  So, `str1` is processed with the first format item `A`, and a string appears.

Come the second output item `str2` we've already used the single format item, reaching the end of the format item list.  The result is that we see this format reversion: that is, we go back to the first item in the list.  After, crucially, we start a new line.

So, if we just want to print those two items to one line (with no space or blank line between them) we could use (neglecting trimming for clarity)

```
print "(A)", str1//str2
```

or we could use a format which hasn't this reversion

```
print "(2A)", str1, str2
print "(A, A)", str1, str2
```

The first concatenates the two character variables to give one, longer, which is then printed as a single output item.  The second prints both individually.

Coming to your particular example

```
character(12), parameter :: str1="Hello"    ! Intentionally longer - trailing blanks
character(12), parameter :: str2=" World!"

print "(2A)", TRIM(str1), TRIM(str2)
end
```

will have output like

```
Hello World!
```

with that middle space because `TRIM` won't remove the *leading* space from `str2`.  More widely, though we won't have the leading space there for us, and we want to add it in the output.

Naturally, concatenation still works (I'm back to assuming no-trimming)

```
character(*), parameter :: str1="Hello"    ! No trailing blank
character(*), parameter :: str2="World!"

print "(A)", str1//" "//str2
end
```

but we can choose our format, using the `X` edit descriptor, to add a space

```
print "(2(A,1X))", str1, str2
print "(A,1X,A)", str1, str2
print "(2(A,:,1X))", str1, str2
```

where this final one has the useful colon edit descriptor (outside scope of this answer).

Comment: Thank you, it now prints on the same line but there's a large space in between the strings.  I want to trim off all spaces except for 1.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4):

Probably close to what you want:
[Concatenate two strings in Fortran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31134182/concatenate-2-strings-in-fortran-90)

`zz = trim(xx) // trim(yy)`

[More info](http://www.cs.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs201/NOTES/chap02/char-opr.html)

[Bing](http://www.bing.com/search?q=string+concatenation+fortran)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this is covered but another useful feature, if you want to print a lot of data on the same line is the following:

```
character(len=32),dimension(100) :: str    

do i=1,100
  write(*,fmt="(A)", advance='no') str(i)
end do
write(*,*) ! to go to the next line when you are done
```

This will print 100 characters on the same line because of advance='no'

Comment: Your syntax for character substring is wrong. Also don't forget to finish the record in the end.

Comment: I suspect he means to use an array of strings. @MarkS you should add the declaration for `str` to clarify.

Comment: Edited to leave less up to your imagination per the comments

Comment: I would like to point out that this, in it's current form, does not print 100 characters per line, but 100 words per line. If you wanted characters, you would need, for example, a single long string, or output a character after character using double indexing but that would require additional modifications to the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use another variable to put those into it, and write those two strings in that new variable:

```
Program combineString
    character(len=100) :: text1, text2, text

    text1 = "Hello,"
    text2 = "My name is X"

    write(text,'(A6, X, A20)') text1, text2

    write(*,*) text

End Program
```

And output is:

```
Hello, My name is X
```