# How to determine the file location in Fortran called from vba excel

Tags: excel, fortran, fortran77, vba

I have an Excel Macro calling an *.exe file created in Fortran. The Fortran code contains `OPEN(UNIT=1, FILE="T13579.txt"...)`. When the *.exe file runs directly there is no problems. When the file is called from Macro, it cannot find the file.
I tried both

```
ABC = Shell(myPath & "\OFE.exe", 1)
Call Shell(myPath & "\OFE.exe", 1)
```

(All files are in the same directory:

```
myPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path)
```

Comment: Use `ChDir myPath` to change the current directory to the location of the file.

Comment: Use generic tags if you want an answer! Almost no-one follows fortran77!!!

Comment: Why the hell do you try the `&`? And how didn't it work? Any error messages?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34622995/how-to-combine-two-strings-in-fortran

Comment: Thank you for your kind response.

Comment: Thank you VF for your kind response. The hell reason of using "&" is that it's the way to concatenate Strings in VBA Excel.  It does work. Excel calls the fortran routine without a problem. However the fortran routine cannot open (find) the file through the operator OPEN. Meantime the direct run of the fortran routine finds the file. That's the problem.

Comment: Thank you YowE3K. I don't see a problem with opening file OFE.exe from VBA Excel. I need to persuade the Fortran to OPEN the file T13579.txt. The problem appears when the OFE.exe stars from Excel.

Comment: Thank you very much YowE3K. ChDir helped!